# Change ListView item background to gradient

Tags: java, android, listview, gradient

I am able to setup a listview using custom adapter which shows correct output..Now i want to change the background of each listview items to a gradient.. how it could be done?

**My files...**

activity_main.xml....Main xml file

MainActivity.java....Main activity

Item.java.... item selector method

ItemAdaptor.... custom adapter

list_item.xml..... item (textView) styling

I have created my gradient code which is like..

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:shape="rectangle">
 <gradient 
 android:startColor="#FFFAFAFA" 
 android:centerColor="#FFFFFFFF" 
  android:endColor="#FFFAFAFA" 
  android:angle="90"/>
</shape>
```

also how could I change the separator color,and the background color of the whole listview..

Comment: put android:background="@drawable/yourgraidentfilename" in list_item.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you mentioned `android:background="@drawable/customshape"` in your rowLayout.xml so that it knows which shape is to be used?  Also use `android:divider="#FFCC00"` in your listview tag  to change the seperator color.    Add  `<solid android:color="#F0F0F0" />` to your shape so as to change the background color.

Comment: how do I name the shape I used android:background="@drawable/rectange" is it correct? inside the textView tag in rowLayout.xml

Comment: I get a gap between the drawable and list background see photo http://s14.postimage.org/5jeuvb4fl/Capture.png  how do I eliminate that

Answer (score 1):

Have a look on this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/)

author created list-view with gradient effect, I think this is exactly what you need.